# Generic Sorting for vector

Tags: c++, templates, sorting, stdvector

I would like to create a generic sorting functor that i can use to sort my vectors. and according to my research, I have come up with the following codes.
But when i implement the sort, I get an the error stated below. Please do advice on how to do it. I need to a generic sort cause I have a few different user defined objects that i need to sort using different criteria.

My Template.h

```
template<typename T, typename M, template<typename> class C = std::less>
struct method_comparer : std::binary_function<T, T, bool>
{
explicit method_comparer(M (T::*p)() const) : p_(p) { }

bool operator ()(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) const
{
    return C<M>()((lhs.*p_)(), (rhs.*p_)());
}

private:
M (T::*p_)() const;
};



template<typename T, typename M>
method_comparer<T, M> make_method_comparer(M (T::*p)() const)
{
return method_comparer<T, M>(p);
}

template<template<typename> class C, typename T, typename M>
method_comparer<T, M, C> make_method_comparer2(M (T::*p)() const)
{
return method_comparer<T, M, C>(p);
}
```

main.cpp

```
std::sort(vec_p2d.begin(),vec_p2d.end(),make_method_comparer(&Point2D::getX())); //ASC
std::sort(vec_p2d.begin(),vec_p2d.end(),make_method_comparer(&Point2D::getX(), std::greater<int>())); //DESC
```

Error:

Assn3.cpp:379:115: error: cannot call member function ‘int Point2D::getX() const’ without object

Comment: `&Point2D::getX` instead of `&Point2D::getX()`

Comment: Is Point2D::getX() a static method? If not, this won't work.

Comment: is Point2D::getX() a static function?

Comment: And then what Fernandes said as well...

Comment: @ScoPi Yes, its a const method.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes You are right on the dot. I removed the () and it worked fantastically.

Comment: It cannot be both static and const.

Comment: @juanchopanza no its only const

Comment: Everyone, i would like to know if i want to compare using 2 values than how can i modify the code?